# Is there a way to display Git Clone progress on a Webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, git, git-clone

I have a field on a webpage were a user is able to enter a repository URL. After the user submits the form I what a prompt to tell the user the progress of the Git Clone like in a terminal. Is there a Javascript function that I could use to make this happen?

Comment: Are you cloning the app for the user? Or you just want the user to do and show the progress on your UI?

Answer (score 0):

If you can call the local git clone command from your HTTP framework ([as done here in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513793/6309)), then you can capture the output (on stderr)

Make sure, if you are calling git clone (on the client) from your Web GUI, [to add `--progress`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956539/6309), since git clone would not run in a terminal (where `--progress` is active by default)

Note also that you are depending on the client Git installation.
For instance, [`--progress` is more precise since Git 2.10 (Q3 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783446/6309).